# How to add image start and end of the video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Here is my code

ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i adapto.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i adapto.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -i empty.mp4 -filter_complex "[2:a]asplit[i][e];[0][i][3:v][3:a][1][e]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] out.mp4

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Nothing video is not created

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: [Parsed_split_0 @ 0000000003a09ec0] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_spli
t_0' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_concat_1' filter input pad 1 (a
udio)
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000006afb80] Cannot create the link split:0 -> concat:1
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Looks like a typo in your command. Make sure it's asplit and not just split.